# Numerically Stable form of Scattering Angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I'm working through the problems in Chapter 3 of the 3rd edition of Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics* and I'm stuck on Derivation 4. This problem asks the reader to rewrite the scattering angle

\begin{equation*}
\Theta(s) = \pi - 2\int_{r_{m}}^{\infty}{\frac{s\mathrm{d}r}{\displaystyle{r\sqrt{r^{2}\left[1-\frac{V(r)}{E}\right] - s^{2}}}}}
\end{equation*}

as

\begin{equation*}
\Theta(s) = \pi - 4s\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\rho\mathrm{d}\rho}{\displaystyle{\sqrt{r_{m}^{2}\left[1-\frac{V(r)}{E}\right]^{2} - s^{2}(1-\rho^{2})}}}}
\end{equation*}

(where $r_{m}$, the distance of nearest approach, is such that $V(r_{m})/E = 1$) via a change of variables $r\to \rho(r)$. To attack this problem, I tried writing

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\displaystyle{r\sqrt{r^{2}\left[1-\frac{V(r)}{E}\right] - s^{2}}}} = \frac{\displaystyle{\frac{r_{m}}{r^{2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{V}{E}}\mathrm{d}r}}{\displaystyle{\sqrt{r_{m}^{2}\left(1-\frac{V}{r}\right)^{2} - \frac{r_{m}^{2}s^{2}}{r^{2}}\left(1-\frac{V}{E}\right)}}}
\end{equation*}

which would seem to hint at $\rho$ of a form such that

\begin{equation*}
s^{2}(1-\rho^{2}) = \frac{r_{m}^{2}s^{2}}{r^{2}}\left(1-\frac{V}{E}\right)
\end{equation*}

or, solving for $\rho^{2}$,

\begin{equation*}
\rho^{2} = 1-\frac{r_{m}^{2}}{r^{2}}\left(1-\frac{V}{E}\right).
\end{equation*}

Unfortunately, this form of $\rho$ doesn't yield the correct bounds of integration, and I haven't even incorporated the Jacobian term

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{d}\rho = \frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}r}\mathrm{d}r.
\end{equation*}

Should I keep working the problem this way, or have I missed something obvious? The physical insight offered by this problem hardly seems worth the effort necessary to solve it (the author suggests its benefit is numerical stability), so I can't help feeling there's an easier way. All the same, I'd love to know what $\rho(r)$ is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\tag1\text{Let }r&=\frac{r_m}{1-\rho^2}
\quad\text{so that}\quad
\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\rho}=\frac{2r_m\rho}{(1-\rho^2)^2}=\frac{2r^2\rho}{r_m}\\
\tag{3.96}\Theta(s)&=\pi-2\int_{r_m}^\infty
\frac{s\,\mathrm dr}{r\sqrt{r^2\left[1-\frac{V(r)}E\right]-s^2}}\\
\tag2\therefore\qquad\Theta(s)&=\pi-4s\int_0^1\frac{\rho\,\mathrm d\rho}{\sqrt{r_m^2\left[1-\frac{V(r)}E\right]-s^2(1-\rho^2)^2}}
\end  {align}
$$
That is, the question had a typo at this point by missing the square on the $(1-\rho^2)^2$ in the square root. If it had it correct, then it would connect to the next form of the integral because $(1-\rho^2)^2=1-2\rho^2+\rho^4$ is needed, with the fact that $\frac{s^2E}{r_m^2}=\frac{\ell^2}{2mr_m^2}=E-V(r_m)$

Comment: Thank you so terribly much! In the errata, the authors mention that in this derivation, " (1-...) in deominator is squared" (sic), and it was unclear that they meant $(1-\rho^{2})$ instead of $[1-V(r)/E]$ (which, already being squared, might seem to have already been corrected in my printing of the book).

Comment: You might be amused that it took me a while to figure out which particular choice of integral would get this correct. It is definitely not trivial.

Comment: In that case, thanks again!

Comment: Incidentally, in the next part of the problem, is it true that the $(2-\rho^{2})$ is correct in the book (i.e. does not need to be squared)?

Comment: I specifically wrote why it is correct. That is my last statement up there.

Comment: Fine. Thank you.